# Is it possible to use % sign in post permalinks?

Tags: permalinks, seo

While working on a client site which is based on deals and offers I found that whenever I am using % sign in the title of the post, it gets removed from permalink.

After doing some research, I found that wordpress removes it automatically to make the URL search friendly. Some people suggested using "percentage" instead of % sign. I believe that using percent word on a deals website is quite awkward.

Is there is any other way to make it possible to use % sign without damaging the SEO of the website? Do you guys think that if I use % sign in the title and permalink removes it, then it will hurt the SEO?

Many PHP websites (not wordpress) which are already using % sign are doing great in Search rankings. How are they making it possible?

Comment: Do you mean that WP removes it from the slug (permalink)? I'm not sure why it would remove it in the post title itself.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I was trying to say that permalink removes the % sign within itself. The % sign in the title remains.

Comment: If you are referring to the permalink/slug, see this answer: https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/how-to-show-percentage-sign-in-wordpress-permalinks/243074

Comment: I was the one who asked it on sitepoint as well. But, as they suggested, I should us "percentage", I think it's quite awkward to use that in a deals based website. I am trying to find a way to use % sign while keeping it seo friendly.

Comment: You might be able to do it via rewrites or a redirection script but I'm not aware of how to do this in WordPress natively. It's 'cleaning' the URLs too stringently - even if you manage to get a % sign in the slug field using %25, it will get stripped out the next time you update the post.

Comment: I think I should not try to find a way of using % in the permalink. But, if it is removed from the permalink, then is it going to hurt seo friendliness of the posts?

Comment: I don't think it will hurt the SEO. I doubt Google uses % symbols in its SEO algorithm given that they're not typically used in URLs in that manner, but rather as special characters.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now I am not worried about that permalink structure. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just answering to close out the question, but if anyone has other opinions please chime in.

No, it's not possible to use % signs in post permalinks without some very hackish workarounds. It's also not advisable given they are used in URLs as special characters. That said, the lack of % symbols in the permalink should not adversely affect SEO as Google and other search engines will already be filtering them out. If you want, edit the post-permalink/slug to use "percent" instead, which Google will understand.